# XUnit - Testando Theory com MemberData Passando uma lista de classes

Tags: c#, testes, testes-de-unidade

Estou utilizando um projeto Xunit para fazer testes na minha API.

Como é minha primeira vez fazendo testes, estou pesquisando como fazer as coisas

Mas estou com um problema que até então eu não encontrei uma solução, que seria na hora de passar instancias de objetos para um metodo de teste

Atualmente eu utlizo um `IEnumerable` para instanciar minha classe e atribuir os valores manualmente

Eu utilizei de duas maneiras que encontrei na internet para testar meus objetos criados

Exemplo 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo 2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma ele acusa erro:
`` System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ServicoBanco.Domain.Commands.ClienteCommand]' cannot be converted to type 'ServicoBanco.Domain.Commands.ClienteCommand'. ``

```
[Theory(DisplayName = "Tratar Valores Recebidos")]
        [Trait("TesteUnidade", "Command")]
        [MemberData(nameof(CommandListTeste))]
        public void TestaCommand_TratarValoresRecebidos_RetornaVerdadeiro(ClienteCommand command)
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
```

Eu quero passar uma lista para a função de teste e que ela receba cada objeto individualmente

Exemplo:

List objetos

MeuObjeto obj1 = new {valores}
MeuObjeto obj2 = new {valores}
MeuObjeto obj3 = new {valores}

// Atribuo meus objetos nessa lista

//Chamo a função de testes

// objetos que é passado por parametro é a lista dos objetos que passei
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(objetos))]
public void TestaCommand(MeuObjeto meuObjeto)
{
// aqui dentro cada "meuObjeto" é uma instancia dos objetos que eu criei a atribui os valores
}

Tem como fazer isso ?

Comment: o problema é que está criando os dados de teste dentro de uma lista, e no método de teste espera um objeto, mude para `new object[] { new ClientCommand(), new ClientComand().... }`

Comment: Poderia explicar como fica ?

Comment: exatamente como coloquei no comentário anterior, no seu primeiro exemplo no lugar de `new List<ClientCommand>..` criar somente cada objeto `ClientCommand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois do Cliente Command eu abro chaves e preencho as propriedades manualmente

```
{
   Id = 1,
   Nome = "Nome",
   // etc
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]